# How do I add column to existing table on module installation?

Tags: hooks

I want to add an extra field to the `users` table from a custom module. I am not sure how exactly can it be done. I'm sure it is done in `mymodule.install` file.
Should I use `db_add_field`, or is there any other way? And where should I implement it? `hook_schema` (but the schema is already defined), or `hook_install`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of giving a (hopefully) complete answer:

- You will need to alter the schema of an existing module, signalling the change to the system. So implement [`hook_schema_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7).
- You will need to implement [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) to actually add the field to the database.
- You will need to implement [`hook_uninstall()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7) as well, to remove the extra field when the module is uninstalled. You might need to do extra cleanup at this stage.

An example which alters the Webform module's webform_submitted_data table:

```
function MYMODULE_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['webform_submitted_data']['fields']['extra'] = array(
    'description' => 'Some random extra info.',
    'type' => 'text',
    'size' => 'big',
  );
}

function MYMODULE_install() {
  db_add_field('webform_submitted_data', 'extra', array(
    'description' => 'Some random extra info.',
    'type' => 'text',
    'size' => 'big',
  ));
}

function MYMODULE_uninstall() {
  db_drop_field('webform_submitted_data', 'extra');
}
```

Comment: this is creating the column correctly in the table. But its not saving the value to the table. any help?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, I went too early to put this as question, but I've figured it out on my local drupal installation. Just added the following code to `MYMODULE.install` file. Used [`hook_install()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) and [`db_add_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_field/7).

```
function MYMODULE_install() {
  db_add_field('users', 'encuid', array(
    'type' => 'varchar', 
    'length' => 60,
    'not null' => TRUE, 
    'default' => 0,
  ));
}
```

Comment: The more bullet-proof way would be to use [`hook_schema_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7), that way all parts of the system (views, `drupal_write_record()`, etc) will play nicely with the new column

Comment: @Clive thank you for the suggestion. I've implemented `hook_schema_alter()`, but the column was not created. Do I need to call it from `hook_install()`, or something else?

Comment: You should disable and UNINSTALL the module after the changes. Then enable it again.

Comment: Sorry about that I wasn't very clear...you should implement that hook as _well_ as physically adding the column to the table with `db_add_field()`

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298493/add-a-new-column-to-the-backend - Can someone check this question?

Answer (score 3):

I think that best method for not loose data is create a hook_update in your custom module and make a drush updb.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_7084().
 * Add new field in custom table.
 */
function my_module_update_7084() {
  db_add_field('mytable', 'my_new_field', array(
    'type' => 'varchar', 
    'length' => 24,
    'not null' => TRUE, 
    'default' => 'favorite',
  ));
}
```

Regards... ;)
Miguel

Comment: Prefer updating the schema changes in [hook_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7.x) and [hook_update_n](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) (both the hooks). Post that, `drush updb` will update the schema changes.