# Trying to add a column of Mysql timestamp through hook_update

Tags: 7, database, updating

I was trying to add the column of MYSQL Timestamp to the Database Table, the Query seems to be working correctly in mysql console.But when I execute the same in db_query() the following error is thrown.

> Failed: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'last_update_date': ALTER
>   TABLE `stores` ADD `last_update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT
>   '0000-00-00 00:00:00';; Array ( ) in store_update_7100() (line 254 of
>   /var/www/slocamo_app/sites/all/modules/store/store.install).

Is the Query.

```
ALTER TABLE  `stores` ADD  `last_update_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Comment: this is not drupal error , remove the ')' at the end then it may work

Comment: @harshal My Mistake, I have copied the wrong error message, Udpated the Error Messgae

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/how-do-i-add-column-to-existing-table-on-module-installation check this out

Comment: @harshal Tried out the same. But No Lock, Tried this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657401/created-and-updated-columns-in-mysql-table-drupal

Comment: did it  work...  ?

Comment: Nope, tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657401/created-and-updated-columns-in-mysql-table-drupal as well it works for One column with data type as timestamp with Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but not for two columns with other having default "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1):

While valid in SQL, there is no data type `TIMESTAMP` in the Drupal 7 database schema.

The list if valid data types is [here](https://drupal.org/node/159605).

This means that you cannot add this datatype  to your tables through any function that goes to the Drupal API (such as `db_query`).  Your SQL console is not subject to these limitations, and will allow it to be added.

So the short answer is: Drupal 7 will not let you do what you try to do.

Also, in case you're trying to add two auto-update timestamps, note the following limitation in [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> One TIMESTAMP column in a table can have the current timestamp as the default value for initializing the column, as the auto-update value, or both. It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.

Comment: Thanks, But I wonder I have used db_query and not db_add_field().Since db_query supposed to execute valid arbitrary query string against the active database.