# Adding a unique key to Drupal column

Tags: database

I'm just doing a one-off script, but I'm wondering if there's a correct "Drupal way" to alter a table and a unique key.

For example, this is essentially the query I want to do:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `node_revision` ADD UNIQUE(`hash`);
```

And then if I later wanted to remove the unique index on hash, how would I also do that?

Does it have something to do with updating the database schema? or possibly `db_change_field()`?

Answer (score 2):

[db_add_unique_key()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_add_unique_key/7) is the function you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_schema_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema_alter/7) and [db_add_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_field/7) in the [hook_install](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) of your module to modify exists tables.

[This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/how-do-i-add-column-to-existing-table-on-module-installation) is on on that exact subject.

Comment: I don't actually want to add the field, though, the field will already be added. I just want to add the fact that the column is unique.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. You were already on the right track with db_change_field.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing how I would add the unique modifier though. How would I do that with db_change_field()?

Comment: Would it just be something like db_change_field('node_revision', 'hash', 'hash', array(), array('Unique' => array('hash')))

Comment: [See this page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7). "unique keys" is the array key you want to use. Also you need to pass in an associative array here.

Comment: And what about the IGNORE part? Is there an easy way to do that?