# How to insert a new column into mysql field data table?

Tags: entities, database

How would I insert a new column into mysql field data table? For example, if I have a field (myfield) with the mysql table field_data_field_myfield having the following columns'entity_type', 'entity_id', 'revision_id', 'bundle', 'delta', 'language', 'myfield_value' and 'myfield_format'...how could I add the column mynewcolumn as type varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding new column in table, please check this discussion [Correct way to add custom column to user table?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112509/correct-way-to-add-custom-column-to-user-table).

Please check this discussion also https://www.drupal.org/node/2616250

Comment: Thanks Vijay! I had already find the answer... It looks the same, so I will give you a check