# how to use user_save with custom column?

Tags: 7, users

I added custom column in users table, i would like to use user_save to create new user programmatically. How can i do that? This code doesn't work for custom columns:

```
$new_user = array(
                        'name' => 'Foo',
                        'pass' => $pwd,
                        'mail' => $email,
                        'signature_format' => 'filtered_html',
                        'status' => 1,
                        'language' => 'en',
                        'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
                        'init' => $email,
                        'custom' => $custom_string,
                        'roles' => array(
                            DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
                            $role->rid => $role->name,
                        ),
                    );

                    $new_account = user_save(NULL, $new_user);
```

Everything except custom gets inserted, if i am not wrong it's default drupal columns for each user's table. Thanks

Comment: Have you added the new column in a Drupal way or manually on the database?

Comment: Hello, manually in the table's structure. What is the drupal way? fields for user?

Comment: I hope the answer below is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding extra columns in tables will rarely work for Drupal as there are dependencies and references that have to be honoured.

The correct way would be something along the lines of [this case](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112509/correct-way-to-add-custom-column-to-user-table).