# Add a new column to the backend

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to add a new column to a table and I added the column using `hook_update_N()`.

```php
function cca_update_8902(&$sandbox) {
  db_add_field('cca_findings', 'cca_topic_id', array(
    'type' => 'float',
      'not null' => FALSE,
      'description' => 'interim fields addition',
    ));
  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->applyUpdates();
}
```

My field is also defined in the `cca_findings` class as property.

```php
class cca_findings extends ContentEntityBase {

  use EntityChangedTrait;
    
  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
    
    $fields['cca_topic_name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string_long')
      ->setSettings(['max_length' => 2047]);
    $fields['meanvalue'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('float')
      ->setLabel(t('meanvalue'));

    $fields['cca_topic_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('float')
      ->setLabel(t('cca_topic_id'));

    return $fields;
  }

}
```

So, the column has been created correctly, but the values are not going on the backend. I feel I am missing something.

What is missing in the code I wrote?

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks for cleaning up the question. Can you help on this? I am struck with this one :(

Comment: You don't need to create the database fields; that is done from Drupal core. I am looking for a Drupal core module that updates its own entity definition, but it's not simple to find one.

Comment: Ahh the table belongs to a custom module. So I don't want to use D8 module. I want to create through my custom module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [Support for automatic entity updates has been removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742), when a module needs to update its own entity, and the update must change the database schema, the module needs to implement [`hook_post_update_NAME()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_post_update_NAME/8.9.x). That is what the Taxonomy module does in [`taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.post_update.php/function/taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable/8.9.x) to make its entity revisionable.

The key code lines in that hook, which show how a new entity field is added, are the following ones.

```php
$definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
$last_installed_schema_repository = \Drupal::service('entity.last_installed_schema.repository');
$entity_type = $definition_update_manager->getEntityType('taxonomy_term');
$field_storage_definitions = $last_installed_schema_repository->getLastInstalledFieldStorageDefinitions('taxonomy_term');
$field_storage_definitions['revision_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
  ->setName('revision_id')
  ->setTargetEntityTypeId('taxonomy_term')
  ->setTargetBundle(NULL)
  ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('Revision ID'))
  ->setReadOnly(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('unsigned', TRUE);
$field_storage_definitions['revision_default'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
  ->setName('revision_default')
  ->setTargetEntityTypeId('taxonomy_term')
  ->setTargetBundle(NULL)
  ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('Default revision'))
  ->setDescription(new TranslatableMarkup('A flag indicating whether this was a default revision when it was saved.'))
  ->setStorageRequired(TRUE)
  ->setInternal(TRUE)
  ->setTranslatable(FALSE)
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE);
$definition_update_manager->updateFieldableEntityType($entity_type, $field_storage_definitions, $sandbox);
```

In your case, the code for `hook_post_update_NAME()` would be similar to the following one.

```php
$definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
$last_installed_schema_repository = \Drupal::service('entity.last_installed_schema.repository');
$entity_type = $definition_update_manager->getEntityType('entity_machine_name');
$field_storage_definitions = $last_installed_schema_repository->getLastInstalledFieldStorageDefinitions('entity_machine_name');
$field_storage_definitions['meanvalue'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('float')
  ->setLabel(t('meanvalue'));
$field_storage_definitions['cca_topic_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('float')
  ->setLabel(t('cca_topic_id'));
$definition_update_manager->updateFieldableEntityType($entity_type, $field_storage_definitions, $sandbox);
```

Replace `'entity_machine_name'` with the machine name of the entity.

Comment: @kiamulaluno where should code go? in the .install file?

Comment: `hook_post_update_NAME()` implementations go in `<module_name>.post_update.php`. Replace `<module_name>` with the module machine name.